# Load Balancing DNS Servers: UDP / TCP

Tags: domain-name-system, load-balancing, haproxy, udp, lvs

I have been asked to rebuild our load balancing infrastructure in the data center.

The original request was to load balance FTP servers. I tried doing that using the current load balancer (**`Piranha / LVS`**), but didn't get it up and running. Not just because there's little to none documentation for this software. Since **`Piranha`** is considered deprecated, I went over to **`HAProxy`** after a couple of days trying, which did the job in a fraction of time spent on **`Piranha`**.

So I've got FTP load balancing (passive mode) in place. Now, I was asked to replace the whole Piranha Load Balancer in the data center. In the current Piranha configuration, we have several web servers, IIS servers....aaaand **DNS**.

No here's the thing:
**`HAProxy`** seems to be a commonly used LB, but **it is not capable of handling `UDP load balancing`**. This is a bummer, since I like how **`HAProxy`** works. 
So I googled a lot and came across several things. Most people seem to use **`LVS`** as a LB for DNS (TCP/UDP). Some use **`dlbDNS`**, some use **`lbnamed`**, and some use **`netfilter / iptables`**.

Since I would want to stick with **`HAProxy`** for FTP, HTTP, IIS servers, I got confused on using it side by side with **`LVS`**.

**Requirements:**
2 LB instances with failover
2 DNS servers (already existent) with failover
Multiple backend servers (http, application, etc...)

**Questions:**
Is this possible? Is UDP load balancing on DNS servers even necessary? Is there any kind of resource that might show me how to get started with that? Or is there a LB solution that is capable to not only handle TCP/HTTP, but also UDP load balancing?


**PS:** The LB solution should be non-hardware and open source / GPL license / free of costs.


Any help or lead to respective resources is much appreciated!

Comment: Check Nginx https://www.nginx.com/blog/announcing-udp-load-balancing/ this seems to address your dns question

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't load balance your DNS.

It's an incredibly light protocol - you'd need an enormous amount of traffic to need more than one box (in which case you'll just be bottlenecking on your load balancer anyway), and there's resilience built in because you can use multiple NS records in your delegation (other servers will be used if one's down).

Comment: Definitely use the multiple NS records, as TCP becomes more common for DNS just let it load-balance itself. Re-inventing the wheel is painful for a reason.

Comment: Multiple DNS servers do offer redundancy and prevent total failure, but a downed DNS server would still cause name resolution delays.

Comment: Okay, makes sense for me. The thing is that I would still need a virtual IP for failover purposes if I'm not mistaking, because we will have 2 machines that will contain the HAProxy and LVS for routing. How would I approach this?

Comment: @MoshPit vrrpd or keepalived are good options.

Comment: I assume you are talking about an Active - Active Hot Standby setup, correct?

Comment: And which of those would you recommend? I've heard about keepalived before, didn't come across vrrpd yet.

Comment: @MoshPit Depends what you want to achieve; vrrpd just does simple VRRP, while keepalived adds stuff like service health checking to determine whether or not the services being load balanced are alive.  Use whichever best suits your needs.

Comment: As mentioned before, I would love to have HAProxy do all the load balancing stuff for HTTP, FTP, etc. and just use keepalived / vrrpd for failover of DNS servers.

Answer (score 11):

I'm uncomfortable with this Q&A because it hasn't really been established what type of DNS server you're talking about. There are some significant misconceptions when it comes to the resiliency of recursive DNS and it's important that people cruising in via search engines don't walk away from this discussion with a false sense of security.

- **Authoritative DNS**: For authoritative DNS servers, the common knowledge regarding the resilience of DNS is pretty spot on. So long as you have multiple authoritative DNS servers that are geo-redundant, you're fine. The main reason for adding high availability for individual IPs is if you're hosting *many* authoritative zones. This allows you to grow your number of servers without having to change the registrar settings for every domain that is hosted.
- **Recursive DNS**: Always use some form of high availability solution. (BGP, appliance, etc.) This is where you can get into some serious trouble. All resolver libraries are not created equal: Windows DNS clients will round robin the initial server used between queries, but the majority of Unix-based systems will always cycle through the list sequentially. What is even *less* known is that these Unix libraries will have to time out *on every search domain* combination before moving on to the next server. If you have multiple search domains configured and the first server in the resolver lookup order is dead, this can create significant delays in DNS resolution for every single request: more than enough to cause problems within your critical applications.

When it comes to recursive DNS, remember that your server infrastructure is only as resilient as the most braindead client configuration. As your company grows, this is something you *never* have control over. Do not make any design assumptions based on a homogonous server OS environment, as things rarely stay the same in a growing company. This will definitely bite someone if you don't plan ahead for it.

Comment: We are using bind / named as a DNS service so far.

Comment: Good point - I was assuming authoritative in my answer but you're right, it may be a recursor.

Comment: @MoshPit Your "DNS service" comment didn't clarify whether this was recursive or authoritative. Authoritative is when you are hosting domains. Recursive is something you would use to get the IP address of domains you don't host. Servers which do both are "mixed", which is against security best practices.

Comment: I apologize for that, noticed that when you posted that comment. We are in control of our own DNS servers, and those are authoritative.

Comment: Don't use a load balancer for high availability.

Comment: @womble I've edited to generalize the need for HA, but I still can't agree with your statement as worded. Handing out the (non-BGP) IPs of your recursive servers is a *terrible* idea unless you're 100% certain that you're a Windows shop and will never, ever, ever become a mixed shop. Anything is better than nothing in this use case.

Comment: What does BGP have to do with deploying a HA service?  It's one (heavyweight) way to do HA, but there's far more appropriate solutions available.

Answer (score 3):

These days you can use `dnsdist` by PowerDNS

From the README

> dnsdist is a highly DNS-, DoS- and abuse-aware loadbalancer. Its goal
>   in life is to route traffic to the best server, delivering top
>   performance to legitimate users while shunting or blocking abusive
>   traffic.
>
> dnsdist is dynamic, in the sense that its configuration can be changed
>   at runtime, and that its statistics can be queried from a console-like
>   interface.

https://github.com/PowerDNS/pdns/tree/master/pdns/dnsdistdist

They provide repositories for common OSes: https://repo.powerdns.com/